# Is ektron regex aliasing change the case of matched group

Tags: regex, query-string, alias, ektron

The url I typed in the browser is like host/en-in/study/subject-**abCD**-**efGh**

I have a regular expression in ektron regex aliasing like

```
host/en-in/study/(.*(.*-([\w_]*)-))([\w_]*)
```

and the mapped url is like below

```
host/ektron_page_path/?pageid=10&subjectid=$3&courseid=$4
```

The values corresponding to $3 and $4 are abCD and efGh

Then the resultant url will be like below

```
host/ektron_page_path/?pageid=10&subjectid=abCD&courseid=efGh
```

My problem is that the query string changed like below when I tried to get them same via using Request.Querystring.Tostring()

host/ektron_page_path/?pageid=10&subjectid=**abcd**&courseid=**efgh**

The case of query string changed to lowercase (abCD to abcd and efGh to efgh)
For fetching the next data query string values to be case sensitive
(abCD fetch the data but abcd not)

Answer (score 1):

I had some email conversation with Episerver support. It was an issue which solved in the ektron 9.1 SP3 Update 8 (June 17, 2016 issue:24315 )